# How to embed a VCL component in a dll and use it in a VCL application?

Tags: dll, c++builder, vcl

I have created a DLL that are using VCL components in its code. The DLL is hiding all C++ code behind a C API.

Using the DLL works fine in a console application.

However, when trying to use it in a regular VCL forms application, I get errors when any code is trying to view VCL frames or forms, e.g.

[image: Error when creating a VCL frame]

I suspect this has todo with linking in the VCL into the DLL.

Question is, do one have to prepare the creation of a DLL using VCL components in some way to avoid this problem? I think it has todo with HINSTANCE somehow?

The reason for creating the DLL in the first place, is to be able to provide a pure C API, so that the code can be used with other compilers, e.g. Visual studio. I would use a package otherwise.

Comment: without MCVE we can only guess. It can be the way you are creating/using VCL stuff inside DLL , or it is just a check in linker on `use RTL` (should be blank) etc... The error message is hinting you created some dynamic VCL class without parrent ... you now `??? = new someVCLclass` instead of  `??? = new someVCLclass(*owner)` or just forget to set `*object->Parrent = *owner;` But as I mentioned without MCVE or at least relevant code sample is this unanswerable

Comment: When displaying VCL Forms in a DLL, you usually need to have the caller pass in an HWND to the DLL so it can be assigned to the DLL's `Application->Handle` for use as the Win32 API Owner for the Form windows.  The `Application` object inside a DLL is separate from the `Application` object of the EXE (if the EXE even has one)